# ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение, помогите исправить

Tags: kivy, мобильные-приложения

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.core.clipboard import Clipboard as Cb
import threading
import socket

KV = """
MyBL:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: (0.95, 0.95)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y":0.5}
   
    Label:
        font_size: "15sp"
        multiline: True
        text_size: self.width*0.98, None
        size_hint_x: 1.0
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1] + 15
        text: root.data_label
        markup: True
        on_ref_press: root.linki()
   
      
    TextInput:
        id: Inp
        multiline: False
        padding_y: (5,5)
        size_hint: (1, 0.5)
        on_text: app.process()
   
    Button:
        text: "Поиск по названию"
        bold: True
        background_color:'#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1,0.5)
        on_press: root.callback()
   
    Button:
        text: "Поиск по описанию"
        bold: True
        background_color:'#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1,0.5)
        on_press: root.callback2()
    
    Button:
        text: "Случайный"
        bold: True
        background_color:'#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1,0.5)
        on_press: root.callback3()
    
    Button:
        text: "Отправить"
        bold: True
        background_color:'#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1,0.5)
        on_press: root.callback4()
    
"""

class MyBL(BoxLayout):
    
    data_label = StringProperty("Фильмопоиск!")
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        SERVER = "192.168.1.37"
        PORT = 1488
   
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client.connect((SERVER, PORT))
        self.client.sendall(bytes("979879789",'UTF-8'))
    
        threading.Thread(target=self.get_data).start()
   
    
    def callback(self):
        print("Поиск по названию")
        self.client.sendall(bytes("Поиск по названию",'UTF-8'))
   
    def callback2(self):
        print("Поиск по описанию")
        self.client.sendall(bytes("Поиск по описанию",'UTF-8'))
    
    def callback3(self):
        print("Случайный")
        self.client.sendall(bytes("Случайный",'UTF-8'))
    
    def callback4(self):
        print("Отправить")
        self.client.sendall(bytes(self.ids.Inp.text,'UTF-8'))
    
    def get_data(self):
        while App.get_running_app().running:
            in_data =  self.client.recv(4096)
            print("От сервера :" ,in_data.decode())
            kkk  = in_data.decode()
            zzz = str(kkk)
            lines = zzz.split('\n')
            print(lines)
            if '\t\t\t\t\t' in lines:
                lines[4] = "==========="
            for ggg in lines:
                if ggg.startswith("https://"):
                    self.ttt = ggg
   
                    ggg = '[ref=linki][color=#00FFCE]' + ggg + '[/color][/ref]'
                self.set_data_label(ggg)
    
    def linki(self):
        print("В буффер")
        Cb.copy(self.ttt)
    
    @mainthread
    def set_data_label(self, data):
        self.data_label += str(data) + "\n"
   
   
    
class MyApp(App):
   
    running = True
    def process(self):
        text = self.root.ids.Inp.text
    def build(self):
   
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    
    def on_stop(self):
        self.running = False
    
MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Ну, просто запустите нужный сервер на указанном IP-адресе с указанным портом, наверное?

Comment: так дело в том, что в качестве сервера выступает мой компьютер

Comment: Ну так сервер-то на нём запущен? Брандмауэр разрешает подключение?

Comment: а как запустить сервер?я думал, что компьютер и его интернет подключение это и есть своеобразный сервер, а насчет брэндмауэра, я его вовсе отключил даже